# NSString stringWithFormat unwanted result

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, nsstring

I want to make sql select sentence like this:

```
NSLog(@"sql = %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Table1 Where ID = %i AND  '%@' = strftime('%Y',startDate)",ID,date]);
```

but it prints to me:

```
sql = select * from Table1 Where ID = 1 AND  '2012' = strftime('Y',startDate)
```

%Y becomes Y, how i could prevent this ?

Comment: FYI, this is really prone to injection attacks. All I have to do is this: date = @"'; drop table Table1; --"; And *poof* your data is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another `%` to escape the `%` character:

```
NSLog(@"sql = %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Table1 Where ID = %i AND  '%@' = strftime('%%Y',startDate)",ID,date]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a % like that `NSLog(@"sql = %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from Table1 Where ID = %i AND  '%@' = strftime('%%Y',startDate)",ID,date]);`